# finding highlighted(preselcted) text using xpath or css

Tags: css, selenium

In following 2 snippets of html  code, I'm trying to create xpath or css for finding if span(Element1 in snippet 1 and Element 2 in snippet 2) are highlighted(preselected) when page is loaded

*Snippet 1*:

```
<div id="idc" class="tre">
  <ul id="idCatT_srt_ul" class="abc">
    <li class="treN treB treSelected" title="Element1 title">
      <span class="spclass">Element1</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*Snippet 2*:

```
<div id="idA" class="tre" >
 <ul id="idAc_srt_ul" class="treChi treRtChil">
  <li class="treeN treB treeLast treSelected" title="Element 2 Title">
    <span>Element 2 Text</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the *treSelected* `class` attribute value denotes that it is preselected, then the following **XPATH** statement would work:

```
span[parent::li[contains(@class,'treSelected')]]
```

It will match on `span` elements who's parent is an `li` element that contains a `class` attribute that contains 'treSelected'.

Comment: Hey Mads, 

Thank you for your reply. However it seems not working. I wrote like this :
String selected= selenium.getText("//span[parent::li[contains(@class,'treSelected')]]")
println(sele)

can you tell me two different xpaths or css based on unique div id for each snippet?

Comment: sorry, ignore my earlier comment regarding not working. It works and find only selected item from snippet 1. Remember both html snippets above exists on same page so both spans are preselected(highlighted)